# Multipart file upload via Powershell Invoke-RestMethod

Tags: python, powershell, api, multipartform-data

I'm trying to upload a file to Webex Teams (messaging app) using API via Powershell. I got this to work with Python but can't seem to make it work with Powershell. Not sure what I'm missing here.

Here's my **Python code** which **works** for **uploading files**:

```
from requests_toolbelt import MultipartEncoder
import requests
filepath = r'C:\Users\user\Documents\myfile.txt'
filetype = 'text/csv'
roomId = 'Y2lzY2........'
token = 'MDZlM2Ni.......'
url = "https://api.ciscospark.com/v1/messages"
my_fields={'roomId': roomId, 'text': 'Hello World', 'files': ('myfile', open(filepath, 'rb'), filetype)}
m = MultipartEncoder(fields=my_fields)
r = requests.post(url, data=m, headers={'Content-Type': m.content_type, 'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + token})
```

Here's my **Powershell code** which **works** for **sending messages**:

```
$BearerToken = "MDZlM2Ni........."
$SpaceId = "Y2lzY2........."
$body = @{roomId = $SpaceId; text = "Hello World"} | ConvertTo-Json
$Url = "https://api.ciscospark.com/v1/messages"
$Headers = @{"Authorization" = "Bearer $BearerToken"; "Content-Type" = "application/json"}
Invoke-RestMethod -Method POST -Headers $Headers -Uri $Url -Body $body
```

Here's my **Powershell code** which **doesn't work** for **uploading files**. What am I missing here compared to the Python code above?

```
$BearerToken = "MDZlM2Ni........."
$SpaceId = "Y2lzY2........."
$body = @{roomId = $SpaceId; text = "Hello World"; files = 'C:\Users\user\Documents\myfile.txt; type=text/csv'} | ConvertTo-Json
$Url = "https://api.ciscospark.com/v1/messages"
$Headers = @{"Authorization" = "Bearer $BearerToken"; "Content-Type" = "multipart/form-data"}
Invoke-RestMethod -Method POST -Headers $Headers -Uri $Url -Body $body
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not a python expert but seeing both codes there are some ambiguities here.

Any response that you are receiving from server will be worth sharing and I just ran some of your commands which are showing that the body although is json formatted but the path to the file is being treated as string which means that the file is not being attached

```
{
    "roomId":  "Y2lzY2.........",
    "files":  "C:\\Users\\user\\Documents\\myfile.txt; type=text/csv",
    "text":  "Hello World"
}
```

Above is the output of the body when I execute your code as you can see that the data from the file is not loaded and in Python code you are opening the file and sending it to the request, you can use the code mentioned below to achieve that

```
$file = Get-Content C:\sample.txt 
$body = @{roomId = $SpaceId; text = "Hello World"; files=$file+'; type=text/csv'} | ConvertTo-Json
Write-Output $body
```

This loads the file contents in plain text and adds it to the json.

The code below is reading all the bytes and attaching that to the body as an attachment

```
$file = Get-ChildItem -Path "C:\\sample.txt"
$file = [System.IO.File]::ReadAllBytes($file.FullName)
$body = @{roomId = $SpaceId; text = "Hello World"; files=$file+'; type=text/csv'} | ConvertTo-Json
Write-Output $body
```

Hope it helps.